# Custom scroll bar flows out of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make my own scroll bar, and so far it's working fine, for this small exception.

When I reach the bottom of the page, the bar handle goes under the viewport.

Gif of what's happening:

[image]

I know it has to do with the CSS, but I'm unsure on how to set it correctly. Foundation's .off-canvas-content has a class added named .full-height, and the height property is added so that the scroll bar won't be tied to that element.
The scroll bar markup is added to div.content, which is where all the remaining content will be.

I'm trying to get the handle bar to stop at the bottom of the container, when the user has scrolled all the way of the bottom of the document, but haven't found a way to do this correctly.

CSS:

```
.scroll-container {
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 7.5px;
    background-color: rgba(55,55,55,.3);
}

.scroll-bar {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #6A1B9A;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.scroller = function() {
        var self = this,
            scrollBarDrag = false,
            docHeight = $(document).height();

        var scrollContainer = document.createElement('div'),
            scrollBar       = document.createElement('div');

        scrollContainer.className = 'scroll-container';
        scrollBar.className = 'scroll-bar';

        scrollContainer.appendChild(scrollBar);

        self[0].appendChild(scrollContainer);

        self.on('scroll', function() {
            var top = $(this).scrollTop();
            setScrollBarTop(top);
        });

        function setScrollBarTop (top) {
            scrollBar.style.top = top + 'px';
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I tried using plugins for this, but they don't simulate the scroll bar as intended (missing mouse wheel click and drag to scroll), so I decided to make my own, lightweight version of it. Any suggestions about using plugins, albeit appreciated, will be disregarded and not accepted as an answer.

With absolute positioning:

[image]

Comment: This has been an issue always with jScrollPane. Are you using it?

Comment: I used jScrollPane yeah, but that's where I wasn't able to use the middle mouse click and drag. Haven't found any other ones that live up to the task.

Comment: That some times sucks if we use abs positioning. Had experienced nightmares. `:(`

Comment: With absolute positioning it's even worse for me, because the layout flow messes up then and I'm able to scroll even further down :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution regarding this, was quite a bit of trial and error, but managed to find it in the end. Hope it can be of use to some of you.

Edited it to a more revised version.

```
self.on('scroll', function() {
    elHeight = self.height();
    docHeight = $(document).height();

    var sTop = self[0].scrollTop;
    var sHeight = self[0].scrollHeight;
    var sBHeight = $(scrollBar).height();

    var ratio = (elHeight - $(scrollBar).height()) / elHeight;
    var currentPosY = (sTop / (sHeight - docHeight)) * 100;

    scrollBar.style.top = (currentPosY * ratio) + '%';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to account for the scrollbar's height. Lets say the scrollbar is 100px tall and your page is 500px tall, you are only able to move the scrollbar by 400px, not all 500.

Find out the difference between your scrollbar height and the document height, find the ratio of how they compare, and apply that to your new scrollbar position.

havent tested it, but something like;

```
var heightToWorkWith = docHeight - scrollBarHeight;
var ratio = heightToWorkWith / docHeight;
function setScrollBarTop (top) {
    scrollBar.style.top = (top * ratio) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. `:)`

Comment: Nope, still goes under the viewport.
I know that the viewport height is 969px, and with the top * ratio it ends up with 1037px.

Comment: not sure how its possible to get a larger number than the doc height from what i posted... the ratio should be less than 1.0 if i did it right. The scrollBarHeight should be the height of the handle element thingy that goes off the screen.

Comment: Checked what the ratio is, it ends up with 0.799~, so the ratio is correct.

Maybe it's taking over the 100% height of a parent element?

Comment: I don't know anything about the rest of your layout, so cant help ya there, but that code should probably work once any other factors in your layout / parent containers etc. are accounted for

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/1028630c3d0744e3c87b3bffc935d079.gif

This is what happens with absolute positioning instead of fixed, so I'm pretty sure it's something with the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get scroll ratio by doing this:

(thumbHeight / containerHeight) + 1

containerHeight is not the scroll area height, but the actual overflow: hidden container.

When you get the scrollTop value just multiply it with your ratio. Like this:

thumbPosition.top = el.scrollTop * ratio + 'px';